# What is the role of the xml key in the SpringFox generated JSON Schema for HATEOAS links?

Tags: jsonschema, spring-hateoas, springfox

We have a DTO in our Spring application that extends `ResourceSupport` to get `_links` generated:

```
public class CustomerDto extends ResourceSupport {      
  ...
}
```

We then use SpringFox to generate the API documentation. Here's a screenshot of the generated models section:

[image]

That's all working fine, but I'm wondering where all the xml attributes are coming from, what their role is and how we can get rid of them?